# New Web Developer- PHP or Javascript for user login

Tags: php, javascript, authentication, passwords

I am trying to create a website that will allow users to login with their email and password. To prepare for this I am attempting to learn the languages that will best help me. I have a knowledge of HTML/CSS and am wondering whether to learn PHP or Javascript first. I understand that PHP is server based, does this mean that I will need to provide a server that, for example, their user names/passwords will be stored on? Also, I have been told that Javascript will sometimes be used in PHP, is it necessary that I learn Javascript first?

Comment: Thanks for the help from everyone. I learned a lot just by reading all of the answers. I have obtained a book on PHP & MySQL and am starting to learn that. I can learn Javascript later if I want to spice up my website. However, I'm just a sophmore in college so I'll have plenty of time for that later. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, PHP is server side (executed on a web server), whilst JavaScript is executed on the client side (in the web browser). JavaScript can't be used "in" PHP, but it's often used to improve the user experience on many web sites. However, for the majority of purposes, it can be considered as a separate concern to PHP.

However, let's take a step back. If you think about your problem, you'll probably come to the conclusion that you need to store the information about the users somewhere on the server side, so that you can check the information supplied in the form against the user data you have stored to see if the details are correct. (Once you learn more, you'll most likely decide to store the information in a database, such as the popular [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index.html), which PHP can talk to and interrogate using the [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) language.)

However, at this stage of things I'd recommend getting hold of a good book on PHP, or perhaps having a look at the i[ntroduction section of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/introduction.php), which contains some basic tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to secure a login is to have the server do the validation. If you do it on the client, anyone can view the page source and see the code. They can even execute arbitrary javascript code, bypassing any client-side validation.

Answer (score 2):

You will need PHP & some database ([MySQL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) is most common) to create a login system.

1. You will need to use forms, send the
   username and password to a script.
2. [Receive](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_post.asp) the data and compare the
   username & password to the one in
   the database
3. If the login credentials are valid,
   create a [session](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php) variable that keeps
   them logged in.

It is worth noting that doing things with only [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) instead of [HTTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Https) allows hackers (read: Script Kiddies) to hijack your user's sessions if they are on an unsecured network such as open Wi-Fi in Starbucks.

Answer (score 0):

Yikes.

At the minimum you want some sort of server-side language. I'd also highly recommend using a pre-built system, depending upon needs, since security is *not* easy.

JavaScript is not required.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need a host to use for a webserver and for a DB, this can also be your pc check out [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
2. Javascript is not required, but using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) can certainly help your UI look a lot better. There are a lot of very simple examples of forms (including a login form) inside the jquery site.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is client-side, it can't auth a user alone, that's were you need PHP. Usually web auth pages don't need javascript, only a client side language, like PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Start with PHP. Javascript is occasionally used for working with PHP on the page (ie., get database info without having to click a "submit" button or navigate to another page.) It is used, for example, to make people's Facebook statuses appear on your homepage in real time. I programmed PHP for years and haven't learned any JS until just recently, so don't worry about it for now.

The posted tutorials (especially on w3) are excellent. There is an excellent tutorial that describes exactly what you are trying to do at [devarticles](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/PHP-for-Beginners-by-a-Beginners/), but it requires a VERY basic understanding of SQL. The example in the tutorial is also fairly unsecure, but it'll teach you the basics of working with MySQL and PHP sessions.

You'll need to run the scripts on a sever that has PHP and MySQL on it, so pay attention to these things when you're looking for hosting.